# Getting all files which have changed in specific time range

Tags: bash

A very basic question in Bash but I can't seem to figure it out.
I'm looking for a one liner command with pipe, in bash which finds in the current directory all the *.py files which have changed last time between 13:15 until 13:30 (does not matter the date).

I think I could use `ls` and `cut` but i'm not sure if it's the write format. looking for a use of the "basic commands".

Comment: Use the `find` command ...

Comment: You will find your answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29253/310674

Answer (score 7):

Use `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.py' -newermt "13:14:59.999" \! -newermt "13:30"
```

Remove 1 millisecond from the lower bound time `13:15` so it includes `13:15:00` modification time.

`find` parameters breakdown:

- `.`: current directory
- `-maxdepth 1`: do not descend sub-directories
- `-type f`: real files (no links or directories or pipes or devices...)
- `-name '*.py'`: whose names match the pattern `*.py`
- `-newermt "13:14:59.999"`: whose modification time is after `13:14:59.999`
- `\! -newermt "13:30"`: and whose modification time is not after `13:30`

Comment: thanks for the help, is it possible to achieve it without `find`, rather with `ls`?

Comment: Parsing `ls` is unreliable. If your version of `find` does not have the `-newermt` option, you can proceed with `touch` files on specific time and tells `find` to return files newer and not newer than these touched files as explained at here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29253/310674