# Count the number of files that modified in specif range of time

Tags: bash

I'm trying to build a one-line command in bash which counts the number of files of type `*.lu` in the current directory that were modified between 15:17 and 15:47 (date does not matter here). I'm not allowed to use `find` (otherwise it would been easy). I'm allowed to use basic commands like `ls`, `grep`, `cut`, `wc` and so on.

What I tried to do:

```
ls -la *.lu | grep <MISSING> | wc -l
```

First of all, I'll find all files `*.lu`, than I need to check with grep the date (which I'm not sure how to do) and than we need to count the number of lines. I think we need to insert also cut to get to the date and check it, but how? Also if current directory does not have `*.lu` files it will fail rather than returning `0`.
How to solve it?

Comment: "fail rather than return a `0`". Not on my system, did you try that? Realize that unless you are using cmds like `rm` or `unlink` there is a very low probabilty of causing any problems with your files. Did you look at the output of `ls -la *.lu`? Where is the data you want to test? make a small test to see if you can capture part of it, then you can move forward. It's not clear what the goal is in learning here, but if regex is part of the course work at this point, you want to figure out how to search for a range of time stamps. `[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]` will give you a place to start. GoodLuck

Comment: it returns `ls: cannot access *.lu: No such file or directory` for `ls -la *.u`.

Comment: yes, and below that, do you see a number? You can hide that error msg with `ls -la *.lu 2>/dev/null | wc -l`. Good luck.

Comment: Do not parse `ls` and look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57385453/getting-all-files-which-have-changed-in-specific-time-range

Comment: @LéaGris As OP said, find cannot be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ls -l *.lu | grep -E '15:[2-3][0-9]|15:1[7-9]|15:4[0-7]' | wc -l
```

Should do it.

With `awk`:

```
ls -al *.lu  | awk 'BEGIN{count=0} {if((substr($8,0,2) == "15") && (int(substr($8,4)) >=17 && int(substr($8,4)) <= 47 )){count++}} END{print count}'
```

UPDATE:

Without `-E`

```
ls -l *.lu | grep '15:[2-3][0-9]\|15:1[7-9]\|15:4[0-7]' | wc -l
```

Redirect error in case of zeros files:

```
ls -l *.lu 2> /dev/null | grep '15:[2-3][0-9]\|15:1[7-9]\|15:4[0-7]' | wc -l
```

Comment: can't use awk or sed either :/

Comment: @abuka123, check the updated answer please.

Comment: its better! but we didn't learn regex or `grep -E`. just `grep -viwnlc`. Sorry :/ Maybe somehow add cut/sort?

Comment: @abuka123, did it without `-E`. It was just for clarity reasons I used that.

Comment: is it possible to redirect the error if there are zero files?

Comment: @abuka123, updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty ugly and can probably be done better. However, I wanted to challenge myself to do this without regexes (excepting the `sed` one). I don't guarantee it'll handle all of your use cases (directories might be an issue).

```sh
ls -l --time-style="+%H%M" *.lu 2>/dev/null |
sed '/total/d' |
tr -s ' ' |
cut -d ' ' -f6 |
xargs -r -n 1 -I ARG bash -c '(( 10#ARG >= 1517 && 10#ARG <= 1547)) && echo ARG' |
wc -l
```

There is probably a way to avoid parsing `ls` via `stat --format=%Y`.